# Why typescript not select the correct Union typed after giving a type guard?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this code:

```
type Fruit = { name: string }
type Car = { name: string }
type PersonOption = 
    | { id: "Michael", fruit: Fruit }
    | { id: "George", car: Car }
type Validation<T> = { validate: () => { success: boolean, result: T } }
type PersonOptionWithValdation<T> = PersonOption & Validation<T>; 

const michael : PersonOptionWithValdation<number> =  { id: "Michael", fruit: { name: "Apple" }, validate: () => ({ success: true, result: 10 }) };
const george : PersonOptionWithValdation<string> =  { id: "George", car: { name: "Apple" }, validate: () => ({ success: true, result: "yes!" }) };
const persons = [michael, george];

function iterate() {
    for (const person of persons) {
        const validationResult = person.validate(); 
        if (person.id === "Michael") {
            return {
                id: person.id,
                result: validationResult.result
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

For some reason, the iterate returns: { id: "Michael", result: string | number }

I expect that it will return { id: "Michael", result: number }
because "Michael" has number as a result. A screenshot attached also.
I would like to know how can i solve this. thanks!

Comment: You combined them into an array and it also combined your generic types which are string and number. You need to use typeguard or typecast it manually

Comment: Is there another solution to achieve this solution dynamically without using typeguards to typecast? Because the purpose of "id" was to be the typeguard itself

Comment: You need to move your validation check after the type guard (inside the if block). Then ts can infer the type correctly.

Comment: I don't want to do that because I want in the future to do a "switch case" statement and I don't want to run person.validate() on each branch

Comment: Well, because your `validationResult` results from a function call. It is not directly related to `person` object according to ts. If it were a property of `person` then it would infer a single type.

Comment: If you convert your `validation()` method into a getter like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wezBYN) it will work as you wish.

Comment: TypeScript only performs narrowing for specific syntactic constructs; it would be prohibitively expensive to make the compiler try to calculate all possible narrowings retroactively; imagine if every time you wrote `if (expr1 === expr2) {}` the compiler had to go back and figure out all logical implications of that equality. The right solution is to only check *after* the type guard, but it's clear from comments here and on deleted answers that you don't want to do that, so… I think we might be stuck. How should we proceed with the question? Answer "no, sorry" or propose a radical refactoring?